# Android Network AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am trying to create a user and POST the user name and password to the server. The code below runs fine in plain java file, but crashed when run in Android due to

> android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException.

I did some search and was told to use AsyncTask but I don't know how to use AsyncTask, how to execute and passing in parameters. I need to pass in url and account Info both are String.

Below is my code that run in plain java file.

```
public String sendPost(String accountInfo, String input_url) throws Exception {

    // Establish Connection
    URL url = new URL(input_url);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setDoOutput(true);

    // Post account info to server
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(accountInfo);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();

    // Check response code and message
    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    IntputStream is = con.getErrorStream();
    String contentAsString = CovertToString(is, 500);
    JSONObject jObject  = new JSONObject(contentAsString);
    jObject.put("response", responseCode);

    return jObject;
}
```

Below is my attempt to make it into AsyncTask.

```
class Test extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            // Establish Connection
            URL url = new URL(input_url);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");
            con.setDoOutput(true);

            // Post account info to server
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes(accountInfo);
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();

            // Check response code and message
            int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
            IntputStream is = con.getErrorStream();
            String contentAsString = CovertToString(is, 500);
            JSONObject jObject  = new JSONObject(contentAsString);
            jObject.put("response", responseCode);

        }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    return null;

    }
}
```

Don't know how to call the method and pass in parameter, and not sure if I implemented the method correctly.

Appreciate any help in advance, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
class Test extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject>{

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {
      JSONObject jObject = null;
        try {
          String accountInfo = params[0];
          String input_url = params[1];
            // Establish Connection
            URL url = new URL(input_url);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");
            con.setDoOutput(true);

            // Post account info to server
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes(accountInfo);
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();

            // Check response code and message
            int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
            InputStream is = con.getErrorStream();
            String contentAsString = CovertToString(is, 500);
            jObject = new JSONObject(contentAsString);
            jObject.put("response", responseCode);

        }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

      return jObject;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject data) {
     // do some things with JSONObject as this runs on UI thread.

  }

}
```

To invoke the task, call

```
new Test().execute(accountInfo, input_url);
```

`onPostExecute` gets called on the UI thread so you can call your UI operations from there..

See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for more information on AsyncTask.

Answer (score 1):

Try to post data as like as:

```
public static String registration(String url,String data) {

    Log.e("REGISTRATION:", data);
    Log.e("REG URL:", url);

    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost postReq = new HttpPost(url);
    List params = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("QueryStr",data));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Action", "REG"));
    String result = "0";
    try {

        postReq.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
        HttpResponse resp = client.execute(postReq);
        if (resp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            HttpEntity entity = resp.getEntity();
            String dt = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

            Log.e("RESPONSE: ", dt); // returned data from server

        } else {

        }
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return result;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass in String parameters to the AsyncTask like this:

```
new AsyncTack().execute(string1, string2, string3);
```

string1, string2, string3 will be forwarded to the doInBackground method,
and you can refer to them like this:

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... params){
    String s1 = params[0] // the original string1
    String s2 = params[1] // the original string2
    String s3 = params[2] // the original string3
}
```

Essentially whatever you feed to .execute() will be passed in as an array to doInBackground.

Note that the doInBackground method runs on a background thread, so you can safely invoke your network operation in it. And if you need to use the returned data to update your UI, modify your AsyncTask to have the doInBackground method return String or JSONObject. The returned data will be passed to the onPostExecute method, which runs on the UI thread, so you can update your UI there.